# Sorting Specific Column in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, data-manipulation

Below is my data frame:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([['A',1,15,100,123],['A',2,16,50,7],['A',3,17,100,5],['B',1,20,75,123],['B',2,25,125,7],['B',3,23,100,7],['C',1,5,85,12],['C',2,1,25,6],['C',3,7,100,7]],columns = ['Group','Ranking','Data1','Data2','Correspondence'])

  Group  Ranking  Data1  Data2  Correspondence
0     A        1     15    100             123
1     A        2     16     50               7
2     A        3     17    100               5
3     B        1     20     75             123
4     B        2     25    125               7
5     B        3     23    100               7
6     C        1      5     85              12
7     C        2      1     25               6
8     C        3      7    100               7
```

I have already sorted the data frame based on 'Group'. However, I still need to sort the data frame based on data for each Group. For each group, Data1 must be sorted based on lowest to highest value and once it is sorted, value in column Data2 will follow the position of Data1. The column Correspondence will not be touched (stay as in original df) and column ranking stays as it is as well. I have used df.sort_values(), but I am unable to get my result as below:

```
  Group  Ranking  Data1  Data2  Correspondence
0     A        1     15    100             123
1     A        2     16     50               7
2     A        3     17    100               5
3     B        1     20     75             123
4     B        2     23    100               7
5     B        3     25    125               7
6     C        1      1     25              12
7     C        2      5     85               6
8     C        3      7    100               7
```

So basically my aim is: sort value in Data1 from lowest to highest within each Group, the value in Data2 will follow the movement of Data1 after sorting, while column Correspondence stays where it originally stands.

Thanks.

Comment: I hate to tell you this, but you are *not* sorted on `Group` (see index 8)

Comment: ah yes, that is my mistake. index 8 is supposed to be C. My apologies for confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with both columns and assign back numpy array with `.values`:

```
cols = ['Data1','Data2']
data[cols] = data.sort_values(['Group','Data1'])[cols].values
#pandas 0.24+  
#data[cols] = data.sort_values(['Group','Data1'])[cols].to_numpy()
print (data)
  Group  Ranking  Data1  Data2  Correspondence
0     A        1     15    100             123
1     A        2     16     50               7
2     A        3     17    100               5
3     B        1     20     75             123
4     B        2     23    100               7
5     B        3     25    125               7
6     C        1      1     25              12
7     C        2      5     85               6
8     C        3      7    100               7
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this?

```py
data2 = data.sort_values(by = ['Group', 'Data1'], ascending = (True, False)).reset_index()
data2['Correspondence'] = data['Correspondence']
```

Comment: Read the demends more carfully

Comment: Now it's what he meant :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
data.sort_values(['Group', 'Data1', 'Data2'], ascending=[True, True, False])
```

And if you want some columns to be descending you have to set that column to `False`.

Comment: Not what he asked for

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `sort_values` function? based on [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) you can do it like this:

```
data.sort_values(['Group', 'Data1'], ascending=[True, False])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use left join (`merge`) as follows

```
df2 = df.sort_values(['Group', 'Data1']).reset_index()
df3 = df2[['Group', 'Ranking', 'Data1', 'Data2']].join(df[['Correspondence']])
df3
```

which will give the result as follows

```
    Group   Ranking     Data1   Data2   Correspondence
0   A   1   15  100     123
1   A   2   16  50       7
2   A   3   17  100     5
3   B   3   7   100     123
4   B   1   20  75      7
5   B   3   23  100     7
6   B   2   25  125     12
7   C   2   1   25      6
8   C   1   5   85      7
```